# Really Need Help About UITouch (Sprite Kit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i Like to create  left side and right side that when i touch them , A bird will fly to the left or right !

1. I create a bird

   ```
   var birdtexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "flappy1.png")            
   bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdtexture)
   bird.position
   bird.size
   bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.width/2)
   bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
   bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
   self.addChild(bird)
   ```
2. Then i create left node

   ```
   var groundleft = SKSpriteNode()
   groundleft.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)
   groundleft.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 100)
   groundleft.color = UIColor(red: 7, green: 5, blue: 7, alpha: 20)


   groundleft.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, 100))
   groundleft.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
   groundleft.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
   groundleft.name = "toleft"
   self.addChild(groundleft)
   ```
3. then i go to TouchBegan

   ```
   let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
   let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
   let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

   if(touchedNode.name == "toleft"){

       bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
       bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-10, 100))

   }
   ```

why it didnt work . Is my method wrong ? Is there any another way for me to make it work ?? 
please help , so many thanks

Comment: All of your titles so far have not been very useful - would you consider writing more descriptive ones? All questions seek help, so "Please help me" and "Really need help" can be removed (if you look at the front page, people very rarely use this, and it often gets edited out). It's much better to explain exactly what the problem is "How to animate an element using SpriteKit?" is better.

Comment: In the body of your question you've said "it doesn't work" but you've not said more than that. What doesn't work? What does happen when you tried to run this? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0):

In your `touchesBegan` method try this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {

        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if nodeAtPoint(touchLocation) == groundleft {   //your sprite node
            //do something

        } 
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)
}
```

Comment: Thank for ur help . i 'll try